# Leak in shower door

Tags: bathroom, shower, leak, water-damage

Help! We have a leak in our shower door, I think it’s from the small gap in the door seal. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this? We have mushrooms growing out of our floor.

https://imgur.com/a/ZO9Q13q

Comment: Sorry , but mushrooms growing out of the floor indicates a much more serious problem. You should be prepared to pull up some of the tiles on the floor and do a more extensive investigation...or hire a bathroom contractor to give an estimate.

Comment: Depending on the type, you might have a new source of money.

Comment: From the photograph, it looks like there is water seeping out from behind and beneath the shower door frame, not a gap in the door seal. Is the wall out of plumb on the inside of the shower as is appears on the outside?

Comment: You need to seal the *inside* of the shower, not the outside.